# ASP .Net MVC simple task

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a problem with one task: When user go on main page see form to enter number and button'Answer'
After when user give number and push button the user receives information:

- "Yes" if number is even
- "No" if number is uneven

That is a `Index.cshtml`

```js
@model WebApplication10.Models.PersonModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" align="center">Give number</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Number)
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Answer" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

This is my `PersonModel.cs`

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication10.Models
{
    public class PersonModel
    {

        ///<summary>
        /// Gets or sets PersonId.
        ///</summary>
        public int Number { get; set; }
       
        
        
    }
}
```

and `HomeController`

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication10.Models;

namespace WebApplication10.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
       [ HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(PersonModel person)
        {
            return View(person);

            
        }

       
    }
}
```

I am beginner in `ASP .Net MVC` and really and I don't how make this, I made a button bu I do not know where and how I should do a function which will check a number>>

Comment: Have you tried anything? Got any code?

Comment: I edited my post,I tried but this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Idk if this is exactly what you want but I added;

```
   <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Number)
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.IsEven)
   </td>
```

and

```
  public class PersonModel
    {

        ///<summary>
        /// Gets or sets PersonId.
        ///</summary>
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string IsEven { get { return Number % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd"; } }


    }
```

Comment: ok,thanks very much,it works but I have one more question :how to make that after I give number new page is open and then I see a statement ?

Comment: So your return view is returning the page based on its name so its looking for index. So you can either change that or do     return View("ViewName",person);

Comment: so in Controller I edited this: public ActionResult Index(PersonModel person)
        {
            return View("ViewName", person);


        } but this didn't work

Comment: ViewName is the view you are wanting it to go to. The new page. So Results or EvenNumberResults whatever the new view you created you want it to go to.

Comment: OK,Now I understood,one more question ,Can I check the value of number in Controller rather than in Model?

Comment: Sure you will just have to set it to something on the model. So keep the property and move the logic.

Comment: I tried in that way in Controlle I add this public string Index(PersonModel value) { public string Index(PersonModel value) { return value.Number % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd"; } ; and this didn't work,WHat I did wrong?

Comment: You need to return a model. So either reuse the PersonModel or create a new one. and do value.WhateverYouwant = value.Number % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd"; return View(value) or return View("OtherViewName",value);

Comment: you know what suddenely this work but I didn't know whether it is right: Index(PersonModel value) { public string Index(PersonModel value) { return value.Number % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd"; } ;-in controller I nithing change and it give me a right answer ,what I should do with this ?